# Javascript alert on incomplete variables

Tags: javascript, html

i'm having troubles on javascript arithmetic.
lets say i have 2 elements from html,

```
var num1 = document.getElementByID('one').value;
var num2 = docuemnt.getElementByID('two').value;

var total = num1 + num2;

alert(total);
```

these two elements are inputted by users. lets say the user left the id='one' blank. how do i make javascript still compute and alert 'total'? can javascript  automatically set the blank field to '0'? i tried this on my project but it will only give me an alert if both 'one' and 'two' were given/inputted. maybe i'm missing something.

Thanks for any help.

**ok this is the code i'm using on my project,**

```
var number = document.getElementById('child1').value;
var hrs = document.getElementById('hrs1').value;
var qty = document.getElementById('qty1').value;
var watts = qty * (number / 1000);
var kwh = watts * hrs;
var kwhh = kwh * 30;

var number2 = document.getElementById('child2').value;
var hrs2 = document.getElementById('hrs2').value;
var qty2 = document.getElementById('qty2').value;
var watts2 = qty2 * (number2 / 1000);
var kwh2 = watts2 * hrs2;
var kwhh2 = kwh2 * 30;

var totalperhr = kwh+kwh2;
var totalper30 = kwhh+kwhh2;

alert(totalperhr + ' kwh per day\n' + totalper30 + ' kwh per 30 days');
```

html below,

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" id="child1">
<select id="hrs1">
    <option value='1'>1hr</option>
    <option value='2'>2hr</option>
    <option value='3'>3hr</option>
</select>
<select id="qty1">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='2'>3</option>
</select>

<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" id="child2">
<select id="hrs2">
    <option value='1'>1hr</option>
    <option value='2'>2hr</option>
    <option value='3'>3hr</option>
</select>
<select id="qty2">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='2'>3</option>
</select>
```

as you can see, i'm going thru several operations then getting the grand total. but i'm not getting any alerts if i leave one blank.

Comment: Sounds odd, it shouldn't throw an error - if the value is empty, it will default to the empty string, which is perfectly concatenatable

Comment: FYI, `<input>` `value` properties are **always** strings, even `<input type="number">`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator to get the number out of the `value` property of your input, or set it to `0`:

```
+document.getElementById('one').value || 0;
```

Code example:

```js
const num1 = +document.getElementById('one').value || 0;
const num2 = +document.getElementById('two').value || 0;

const total = num1 + num2;

console.log(total);
```

```html
<input type="number" value="5" name="one" id="one">
<input type="number" value="" name="two" id="two">
```

**Note**: instead of `document.getElementByID()` you should write `document.getElementById()`

Your code:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('#child1, #hrs1, #qty1, #child2, #hrs2, #qty2');
const values = {
  child1: 0,
  hrs1: 0,
  qty1: 0,
  child2: 0,
  hrs2: 0,
  qty2: 0
};
const getTotals = () => {
  elements.forEach(elem => values[elem.id] = +elem.value || 0);

  const watts = values.qty1 * (values.child1 / 1000);
  const kwh = watts * values.hrs1;
  const kwhh = kwh * 30;

  const watts2 = values.qty2 * (values.child2 / 1000);
  const kwh2 = watts2 * values.hrs2;
  const kwhh2 = kwh2 * 30;

  const totalperhr = kwh + kwh2;
  const totalper30 = kwhh + kwhh2;

  console.clear();
  console.log(values);
  console.log(totalperhr + ' kwh per day\n' + totalper30 + ' kwh per 30 days');
};

elements.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('change', getTotals));
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" id="child1">
<select id="hrs1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1hr</option>
  <option value="2">2hr</option>
  <option value="3">3hr</option>
</select>
<select id="qty1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>

<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" id="child2">
<select id="hrs2">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1hr</option>
  <option value="2">2hr</option>
  <option value="3">3hr</option>
</select>
<select id="qty2">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hi sir, i edited my question above with my actual code i'm using. i tried this but can't get it to work.

Comment: -1, the answer is misleading. As @CertainPerformance has pointed out "*if the value is empty, it will default to the empty string, which is perfectly concatenatable*". I. e., `console.log(42 + '');` returns `42`. This snippet will also work after removing the unary operator and the `|| 0`.

Comment: @David that is a not good comment. I will never recommend to anybody that uses a `string` in a matematic operation.. Because if there is a number what will happen?: `console.log(42 + '0');` return `420`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero - That's completely correct. I didn't say that your answer is wrong. I said that is misleading because clearly that's not the OP problem. At least, not the only one.

Comment: @KimLo I have added a code refactor to your original code in order to show in console all the `value`s for any change on the form elements... Hope it helps

Comment: @YosvelQuintero will try this out now and see if it will work on my code.